# How can I sort tuples by reverse, yet breaking ties non-reverse? (Python)

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, reverse

If I have a list of tuples:

```
results = [('10', 'Mary'), ('9', 'John'), ('10', 'George'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'Adam')]
```

How can I sort the list as you might see in a scoreboard - such that it will sort the score from biggest to smallest, but break ties alphabetically by name?

So after the sort, the list should look like:

```
results = [('10', 'George'), ('10', 'Mary'), ('9', 'Adam'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'John')]
```

At the moment all I can do is `results.sort(reverse=True)`, but breaks ties reverse alphabetically too...

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `'10' < '9' is True` and `'Adam' < 'Frank' is True`. I guess you want make `'10' > '9'`?

Comment: Why do you have strings instead of ints for your numbers?

Comment: That's a good point!! I didn't think about that. All my numbers are ints now, but I'm still unsure as to how to sort reverse and break ties non-reverse...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use the fact that python sort is stable. This allows to first sort alphabetically and then by score:

```
In [11]: results = [(10, 'Mary'), (9, 'John'), (10, 'George'), (9, 'Frank'), (9, 'Adam')]

In [12]: results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

In [13]: results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

In [14]: results
Out[14]: [(10, 'George'), (10, 'Mary'), (9, 'Adam'), (9, 'Frank'), (9, 'John')]
```

The first sort sorts alphabetically, in ascending order. The second sort sorts by score, in descending order, maintaining the relative order of elements with equal score.

You can do this to do even more complex sorts. Just remember that you must first sort by the *secondary* key, and then by the first key. (If you have three keys, first sort by the third, then by the second, and lastly by the main key).

If you don't want to call `sort` twice you'll have to write a more complex `key` function. Something like:

```
In [50]: def key(elem):
    ...:     return elem[0], [-ord(c) for c in elem[1]]

In [51]: sorted(results, key=key, reverse=True)
Out[51]: [(10, 'George'), (10, 'Mary'), (9, 'Adam'), (9, 'Frank'), (9, 'John')]
```

In particular, every time you have something sorted in lexicographic order(such as strings, tuples, lists etc.), you can invert the order by changing the sign to all the elements.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you can avoid some of the complexity in your "one sort call" example by using the default ascending sort and reversing the number instead of the string `sorted(results, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))`

Answer (score 7):

`sort` method accept optional `key` parameter.

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element

You need to convert string to number:

```
>>> results = [('10', 'Mary'), ('9', 'John'), ('10', 'George'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'Adam')]
>>> results.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[0]), x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> results
[('10', 'Mary'), ('10', 'George'), ('9', 'John'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'Adam')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have very granular control on how to sort each of the values in a tuple with `sort` method's `key` parameter. For example:

```
In [41]: results = [('10', 'Mary'), ('9', 'John'), ('10', 'George'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'Adam')]

In [42]: results.sort(key=lambda (score, name): (-int(score), name))

In [43]: results
Out[43]: 
[('10', 'George'),
 ('10', 'Mary'),
 ('9', 'Adam'),
 ('9', 'Frank'),
 ('9', 'John')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just using `sorted` should suffice

```
>>> sorted(results)
[('10', 'George'), ('10', 'Mary'), ('9', 'Adam'), ('9', 'Frank'), ('9', 'John')]
```

default `cmp` function checks precedence of a tuple by comparing each member of tuple, from 0 to n, in that order

Comment: Ah, I see - problem is that if the numbers are anything else, this wont work... bad example I suppose :) sorry