# Sorting 2D Lists by Key

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a 2D List -

```
[('John', 7), ('Max', 10), ('Sarah', 10), ('Tara', 7)]
```

which I would like to sort by number descending (highest first) and then name (alphabetical).

I have used this code -

```
highestscore = sorted(highestscore, key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)
```

but I get the result

```
[('Sarah', 10), ('Max', 10), ('Tara', 7), ('John', 7)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not reversing the list? I mean the output looks correct to me, that Sarah has the highest score a long with Max and then Tara and John.

Comment: Instead of reassigning the result of `sorted()` to the same variable, you can just sort in place: `highestscore.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mix descending order (score) with ascending (name). You may just use -`x[1]` instead of `reverse=True`:

```
highestscore = sorted(highestscore, key = 
    lambda x: (int(-x[1]), x[0].lower()))
```

I also added `lower()` to make alphabetical ordering case insensitive. The result is `[('Max', 10), ('Sarah', 10), ('John', 7), ('Tara', 7)]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about try this:

```
a = [('John', 7), ('Max', 10), ('Sarah', 10), ('Tara', 7)]
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

The result is:

```
[('Max', 10), ('Sarah', 10), ('John', 7), ('Tara', 7)]
```

Refererence: [How can I sort tuples by reverse, yet breaking ties non-reverse? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414995/how-can-i-sort-tuples-by-reverse-yet-breaking-ties-non-reverse-python)

Answer (score 0):

You sorting is all right... You need to transform your elements with a map afterwards.

```
highestscore = sorted(highestscore, key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)

scores = [ ( x[ 1 ], x[ 0 ] ) for x in highestscore ]
```

The result will be

```
[(10, 'Max'), (10, 'Sarah'), (7, 'John'), (7, 'Tara')]
```